# How to sort a list alphabetically in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I am generating a list of centres, but because the centres are a child of borough, I was wondering how to sort the iteration alphabetically in the views.

My code looks like this

```
        <% boroughs.each do |borough|%>
          <% if borough.leisure_centres.any? %>
            <% borough.leisure_centres.each do |venue| %>
            <li class="sitemap-accordion">
              <%= link_to venue.title, '#', class: "trigger" %>
                <ul class="sitemap-accordion-child">
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to "Overview", centre_path(venue) %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to 'News', centre_news_index_path(venue) %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to 'Facilities', facilities_centre_path(venue) %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= link_to 'Contact Us', new_centre_contact_form_path(venue) %>
                  </li>
                  <% unless venue.venue_hire_content.nil? %>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to 'Hire', venue_hire_centre_path(venue) %>
                    </li>
                  <% end %>
                  <% unless venue.virtual_tour.nil? %>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to 'Virtual Tour', tour_centre_path(venue) %>
                    </li>
                  <% end %>
                  <% unless venue.custom_pages.nil? %>
                    <% venue.custom_pages.each do |custom_page| %>
                      <li>
                        <%= link_to custom_page.title, centre_custom_page_path(centre_id: venue, id: custom_page.id) %>
                      </li>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              <% end %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

I would like `venue.title` to be in alphabetical order, how do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: `leisure_centre` is it's own model?

Comment: good shout homeslice, so, how do i do it in the views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

Rails 4

```
class Borough < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leisure_centres, -> { order "title asc" }
end
```

Rails 3

```
class Borough < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leisure_centres, :order => "title asc"
end
```

So you are sorting via SQL not ruby.

Comment: goo shout, but "syntax error, unexpected ->, expecting keyword_end
  has_many :leisure_centres -> { order "title asc" }"

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: ahh, i changed to =>   i am ona legacy project so the rails vis  a tad older. still doesn,t work though

Comment: Which version of rails then?  and why have you tagged it rails 4 if you're not using rails 4?

Comment: my bad, ill change it, rails 3.2

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a block to sort_by method like this.

```
<% borough.leisure_centres.sort_by(&:title).each do |venue| %>
```

Comment: beat me by 11 seconds!

Comment: yeah. That was close :P

Comment: yeah, but that sorts the leisure centres by boroughs?